# Need help to create a Custom database for Website

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

Need advice designing a new website that needs a calendar of events & a database of social services organizations of less than 1k records. How easy can this be done with Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) and a calendar plugin? Any opinion appreciated. Any clues appreciated. Thank you.